# Formatting Partitions in ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, partitioning, format, fdisk

Hi I create 2 primary partitions with `fdisk` and I know that I have to format them in next step, how can I format them together instead of running `mkfs -t ext4` twice?

Comment: Take a look at `man mke2fs`. You cannot mount these partitions unless they are formatted, so the mount-command you suggest will simply fail.

Comment: Formatting and mounting are two separate steps. Once the disks are formatted, you can have them auto mount if you want by configuring `/etc/fstab`

Comment: "how can I format them together instead of running mkfs -t ext4 twice?" not possible This is 2 commands. And why is that a problem?